# Using nodejs modules for html web page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, function, base64

I am working on a small project that Base64 encodes a string, and then hashes it.

I'm using Nodejs to host the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function onRequest(request, response){
  response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  fs.readFile('./index.html',null, function(error, data){
    if (error) {
      response.writeHead(404);
      response.write('file not found');
    } else {
        response.write(data);
    }
    response.end();
  });
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
console.log('server is running!');
```

On the HTML page, I have created a table in which the left cell will be the encoded data, and the right will be the hash value.

```
  <div class="container">
    <table id="table" class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Encode</th>
          <th>Encrypt</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
```

To generate the values I am using the following:

```
<button onclick="addData()">Add a Row</button>
```

This script is referenced at the top of the HTML.

Finally, here is the JS that is filling in the cells as the button is clicked:

```
function addData(){
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var row = table.insertRow(1); //which number row the data is added from. row 0 is for the titles.
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //left cells
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); //right cells
cell1.innerHTML = encode("value");
cell2.innerHTML = encrypt("value");
}
```

If I remove `encode` and `encrypt` and just supply a value, it works. But when I introduce my two functions to encode and then encrypt, the HTML prints out the entirety of the function.

Functions:

```
function encode(string) {

  let buff = new Buffer(string);
  let base64data = buff.toString('base64');
  return base64data;
}

function encrypt(string) {
  let crypto = require('crypto');
  let hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(string).digest('base64');
  return hash;
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined[Learn More]
```

So my question is, why can I not use my functions that are using nodeJS modules?

Comment: "why can I not use my functions that are using nodeJS modules?" — Because `Buffer` is not defined in the browser (and you have done nothing to make it defined).

Comment: because your html, and javascript runs after coming on to browser and there is no Buffer function available in browser.
So what you can do is extract Buffer function from node module and write that in your javascript code.

Comment: @mez0 your both function (encode & encrypt) both are execute on client so there is no scope of your node server you are not able to access node packages if you have to need this module then inject your js using script tag.